# Azure Function deploy says successful but does not show up

Tags: visual-studio, azure, serverless

Using the Azure Functions tools in Visual Studio Code, I'm trying to deploy an Azure function. I click on the app to deploy to and everything shows successful:

```
2:24:17 PM azureuser01: Omitting next output lines...
2:24:31 PM azureuser01: Waiting for long running command to finish...
2:24:48 PM azureuser01: Running post deployment command(s)...
2:24:50 PM azureuser01: Syncing 3 function triggers with payload size 291 bytes successful.
2:24:51 PM azureuser01: Deployment successful.
Deployment to "azureuseracct" completed.
```

I'm using:

Visual Studio Code - Insiders Version 1.26.0-insider

Azure Functions 0.10.0

Azure Resource manager 0.4.2

Any Ideas? Where to look for issues?

Comment: Have you checked on portal or this site `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`. You should see folders named after your functions and there are files like `function.json` inside.

Comment: Ok I see changes to files if I choose to overwrite an existing function app. If I deploy to a new function app, the function app name shows up but the function does not... not sure what is going on.

Comment: Everything works on my side, could you check whether your files are published to Azure following the tip I suggest? Or could you offer detailed steps to repro your problem?

Comment: creating a new function app creates a new function app, but under the functions section no actual function is visible

Comment: Hi TyMac, did you find any solution? you could post it for others to refer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not forgetting to declare the function name, e.g.
`[FunctionName("DeviceDataReceived")]` right above the main run.